# Обработка GET запроса по одному URL

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Есть список юзеров на /user/all. Как сделать что бы в контроллере можно было обрабатывать GET запросы такого типа /user/all?name=Ivan

Если в контроллере написать два метода

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/all", method = "RequestMethod.GET")
public String allUser() {
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/user/all", method = "RequestMethod.GET")
public String allUserParam(@RequestParam("name") String name) {
}
```

То будет ошибка, потому что метод GET по этому URL уже есть. Как тогда делать? И еще вопрос, если написать вот так

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/all", method = "RequestMethod.GET")
public String allUserParam(@RequestParam("name") String name) {
}
```

Но в адресной строке параметра "name" не будет, то будет ошибка. Как проверить на существование этого параметра? Как сделать что б не было ошибки, если юзер сам руками стер его?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Раз параметр опционален, отразите это в аннотации:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/all", method = "RequestMethod.GET")
public String getUser(@RequestParam("name", required=false) String name) {
    if (name != null) {
    } else {
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое